# 405 error returned when using POST method in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

I'm using Jersey and have had no problem with `GET` and `PUT` calls but for some reason `POST` refuses to work; I keep getting a 405 returned.

I've tried multiple permutations for the signature on my method and I'm starting to wonder if there is something else I'm missing.

Here's an example of what won't work:

Server-side:

```
@Path("/tmm")

public class TmmRes  {

@POST
@Path("/mypost")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postTest(String input) {
    System.out.println("Made it to POST: "+input);
    return Response.status(201).entity(input).build(); 
}
```

}

Client-side:

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8888/api/v1").path("tmm").path("mypost");
String input = "{\"address\":\"myaddress\",\"user\":4}";
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, input);
```

I realize that using `JSON` I should have an object that the input binds to, but I've reduced the complexity to simply get the thing working.

Anybody have any insight? By the way, I'm using `Tomcat (6.0.43)`.

Comment: Did you tried doing the same request but using POSTMAN (the chrome app, not the chrome browser extension)? So you can see the real HTTP request, content-type, etc. It seems like the content-type text/json is not done properly.

Comment: Yes, I've tried POSTMAN with the same result. I was wondering if there was something unique about POST that requires some extra setup on the server side. I've also been able to get DELETE working...

Comment: This code it's working under my setup, either you are missing the path or having troubles with the version of tomcat or maybe jersey. Have you tried to change all the POST to PUT in this particular code and that is working? or you have other methods annotated with PUT that works?

Comment: Thanks for trying it... Yes, I tried changing POST to PUT and changing to 'put' on the client-side and it works. There's something about POST that my setup doesn't like. Is there anything special in your web.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with the help of a friend, I was able to figure this out. My URL was hitting a redirect. This was causing my POST to turn into a GET. Thanks for the help everyone. Your confirmations eliminated possibilities and helped guide me to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to create a POJO like this:

```
public class User {

private String address;
private Integer user;

// getters and setters

}
```

and then change

```
@POST
@Path("/mypost")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postTest(String input) {
    System.out.println("Made it to POST: "+input);
    return Response.status(201).entity(input).build(); 
}
```

to:

```
@POST
@Path("/mypost")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response postTest(User input) {
    System.out.println("Made it to POST: "+input);
    return Response.status(201).entity(input).build(); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it gives me the same problem. I'm wondering if there is some sort of security issue I'm missing (although PUT,DELETE work).

Comment: I don't think it is any security issue. Can you post the full request you get from postman?

Comment: This is what I'm sending:                                                                                    POST /api/v1/tmm/mypost HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 8463180a-34b8-fdad-5cd6-adbeb52e9d90

    {
        "user" : "joeschmoe",
        "address" : "here"
   }

Comment: I noticed that the request object being passed into the class(TmmRes) has a value of 'GET' for the httpMethod. It appears that Jersey is changing my POST request into a GET request. Has anyone seen this behaviour before?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this in IntelliJ.

Go to the menu: BUILD ->BUILD ARTIFACTS -> BUILD or REBUILD and that's it.